# Elixir - Making DNS Queries (Using dig command)

Tags: elixir

I need to create a DNS request and get a response.
I run this command in Linux(Ubuntu) to send a request and get a response:

```
dig +nocmd google.com txt +noall +answer
```

Response:

```
google.com.             3400    IN      TXT     "facebook-domain-verification=22rm551cu4k0ab0bxsw536tlds4h95"
google.com.             100     IN      TXT     "docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e"
google.com.             100     IN      TXT     "docusign=1b0a6754-49b1-4db5-8540-d2c12664b289"
google.com.             3400    IN      TXT     "globalsign-smime-dv=CDYX+XFHUw2wml6/Gb8+59BsH31KzUr6c1l2BPvqKX8="
google.com.             3400    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Can I use ***dig*** command in Elixir? Perhaps there are libraries that can help me solve this problem. Unfortunately, so far I have not been able to find such libraries. I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at [`System.cmd/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3)? If you want to use `dig`, that is probably your best bet.

Comment: @JustinWood System.cmd("whoami", []) - for example, this command work, but when I try run System.cmd("dig +nocmd google.com txt +noall +answer", []) I have an error: "(ErlangError) Erlang error: :enoent. (elixir 1.10.2) lib/system.ex:795: System.cmd("dig +nocmd google.com txt +noall +answer", [], [])"

Comment: `"dig" |> System.cmd(~w|+nocmd google.com txt +noall +answer|) |> elem(0) |> IO.puts()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.cmd` like:

```
{result, _status} =
  System.cmd(
    "dig",
    ["+nocmd", "google.com", "txt", "+noall", "+answer"]
  )

String.split(result, "\n", trim: true)
|> Enum.map(&String.split(&1, "\t", trim: true))
```

you get something like

```
[
  ["google.com.", "3599", "IN", "TXT", "\"globalsign-smime-dv=CDYX+XFHUw2wml6/Gb8+59BsH31KzUr6c1l2BPvqKX8=\""],
  ["google.com.", "3599", "IN", "TXT", "\"facebook-domain-verification=22rm551cu4k0ab0bxsw536tlds4h95\""],
  ["google.com.", "3599", "IN", "TXT", "\"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all\""],
  ["google.com.", "299", "IN", "TXT", "\"docusign=1b0a6754-49b1-4db5-8540-d2c12664b289\""],
  ["google.com.", "299", "IN", "TXT", "\"docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e\""]
]
```

Answer (score 5):

While you can shell out to `dig` or other DNS resolving command it is better to use DNS resolving features built in into Erlang:

```
{:ok, res} = :inet_res.nslookup('google.com', :in, :txt)
txt_rr =
  res
  |> :inet_dns.msg()
  |> Keyword.fetch!(:enlist)
  |> Enum.map(&:inet_dns.rr/1)
```

Will result with:

```
[
  [
    domain: 'google.com',
    type: :txt,
    class: :in,
    ttl: 94,
    data: ['globalsign-smime-dv=CDYX+XFHUw2wml6/Gb8+59BsH31KzUr6c1l2BPvqKX8=']
  ],
  [
    domain: 'google.com',
    type: :txt,
    class: :in,
    ttl: 94,
    data: ['facebook-domain-verification=22rm551cu4k0ab0bxsw536tlds4h95']
  ],
  [
    domain: 'google.com',
    type: :txt,
    class: :in,
    ttl: 94,
    data: ['docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e']
  ],
  [
    domain: 'google.com',
    type: :txt,
    class: :in,
    ttl: 94,
    data: ['docusign=1b0a6754-49b1-4db5-8540-d2c12664b289']
  ],
  [
    domain: 'google.com',
    type: :txt,
    class: :in,
    ttl: 94,
    data: ['v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all']
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `inet_res.nslookup` is [deprecated](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet_res.html#legacy-functions), here are two alternatives:

You could use [`lookup/3`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet_res.html#lookup-3) which looks way more convenient:

```
> :inet_res.lookup('google.com', :in, :txt)
[
  ['docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e'],
  ['apple-domain-verification=30afIBcvSuDV2PLX'],
  ['globalsign-smime-dv=CDYX+XFHUw2wml6/Gb8+59BsH31KzUr6c1l2BPvqKX8='],
  ['docusign=1b0a6754-49b1-4db5-8540-d2c12664b289'],
  ['v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all'],
  ['google-site-verification=wD8N7i1JTNTkezJ49swvWW48f8_9xveREV4oB-0Hf5o'],
  ['facebook-domain-verification=22rm551cu4k0ab0bxsw536tlds4h95'],
  ['google-site-verification=TV9-DBe4R80X4v0M4U_bd_J9cpOJM0nikft0jAgjmsQ'],
  ['MS=E4A68B9AB2BB9670BCE15412F62916164C0B20BB']
]
```

Or, since [`lookup/3`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet_res.html#lookup-3) calls [`resolve/3`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet_res.html#resolve-3) in the background, you can call `resolve/3` directly to have a more verbose experience if you need e.g. the TTL or have an error message in case something goes wrong:

```
> :inet_res.resolve('google.com', :in, :txt)
{:ok,
 {:dns_rec, {:dns_header, 3, true, :query, false, false, true, true, false, 0},
  [{:dns_query, 'google.com', :txt, :in, false}],
  [
    {:dns_rr, 'google.com', :txt, :in, 0, 690,
     ['docusign=05958488-4752-4ef2-95eb-aa7ba8a3bd0e'], :undefined, [], false},
    {:dns_rr, 'google.com', :txt, :in, 0, 690,
     ['apple-domain-verification=30afIBcvSuDV2PLX'], :undefined, [], false},
    {:dns_rr, 'google.com', :txt, :in, 0, 690,
     ['globalsign-smime-dv=CDYX+XFHUw2wml6/Gb8+59BsH31KzUr6c1l2BPvqKX8='],
     :undefined, [], false},
    {:dns_rr, 'google.com', :txt, :in, 0, 690,
     ['docusign=1b0a6754-49b1-4db5-8540-d2c12664b289'], :undefined, [], false},
    {:dns_rr, 'google.com', :txt, :in, 0, 690,
     ['v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all'], :undefined, [], false},
    {:dns_rr, 'google.com', :txt, :in, 0, 690,
     ['google-site-verification=wD8N7i1JTNTkezJ49swvWW48f8_9xveREV4oB-0Hf5o'],
     :undefined, [], false},
    {:dns_rr, 'google.com', :txt, :in, 0, 690,
     ['facebook-domain-verification=22rm551cu4k0ab0bxsw536tlds4h95'],
     :undefined, [], false},
    {:dns_rr, 'google.com', :txt, :in, 0, 690,
     ['google-site-verification=TV9-DBe4R80X4v0M4U_bd_J9cpOJM0nikft0jAgjmsQ'],
     :undefined, [], false},
    {:dns_rr, 'google.com', :txt, :in, 0, 690,
     ['MS=E4A68B9AB2BB9670BCE15412F62916164C0B20BB'], :undefined, [], false}
  ], [], []}}
```

Disclaimer: I'm an elixir beginner.